# let $\forall x \neq 0 \ \ \ f(x+\frac{1}{x})=x^2-\frac{1}{x^2}$ then find the $f(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> let $\forall x \neq 0  \ \ \ f(x+\frac{1}{x})=x^2-\frac{1}{x^2}$ then find the $f(x)$

---

My try :

$$x^2-\frac{1}{x^2}=(x+\frac{1}{x})(x-\frac{1}{x})$$

And $$(x-\frac{1}{x})^2 =(x+\frac{1}{x})^2-4$$

so we have :

$$f(t)=\pm t \sqrt{t^2-4}$$

it is right ?

Comment: The "so we have" part and following I didn't understand...and your function is defined only for $\;|t|\ge2\;$ , whereas the given function doesn't have this condition. Yet...

Comment: @DonAntonio Makes sense to me. we have $t = x + 1/x$, so $x-1/x = \pm\sqrt{t^2-4}$

Comment: How about $f(t) = t^2-2$?

Comment: @md2perpe That would only work if it was $x^2 + 1/x^2$

Comment: @Dylan Well, what I was trying the OP to come up with is that the equation $\;x+\frac1x=\alpha\;$ has a real solution iff $\;|\alpha|\ge2\;$ ....so the "condition in his function isn't **in fact** different from the original function's...

Comment: The condition $|x| \ge 2$ isn't really important (or given). All we need is $x + 1/x$ exists for $\forall x \ne 0$ and that $f(x+1/x)$ exists for every value of $x+1/x$

Comment: Ah, I see now that I missed the minus sign in the right hand side.

Comment: A similar but different question [Given $f(x+1/x) = x^2 +1/x^2$, find $f(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220912/given-fx1-x-x2-1-x2-find-fx)

Answer (score 5):

Such function cannot exist. Take $x=2$, then we have $$f(2+1/2)= 4-1/4= 15/4$$ Now take $x=1/2$, then we have $$f(2+ 1/2)=1/4-4=-15/4$$But $-15/4\neq 15/4$. Hence such function cannot exist.